# How do I remove the elements of vector that occur in another vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want the disjoint result. This is the best I can come up with:

```rust
for rem in &remove_vec {
    orig_vec.retain(|i| !i.eq(rem));
}
```

Comment: That's going to run in *O(o×r)* where *o* and *r* are the number of items in `orig_vec` and `remove_vec`. I suggest converting `remove_vec` to a set which will take *O(r)* time and then removing in *O(o)* time. *O(o+r)* is substantially faster than *O(o×r)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. Instead, convert the items to remove into a set, either `BTreeSet` or `HashSet`:

```rust
use std::{collections::BTreeSet, iter::FromIterator};

fn demo<T>(mut items: Vec<T>, to_remove: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::cmp::Ord,
{
    let to_remove = BTreeSet::from_iter(to_remove);

    items.retain(|e| !to_remove.contains(e));

    items
}
```